# Pro Lighting Skies Ultimae. "Upgrade required to 2.8" error on 2.82

Tags: add-on, lighting

I installed 'Pro Lighting Skies Ultimate' with no problem, but it's not working because on the preferences tab it says 'upgrade to 2.8x required', even though I'm running 2.82. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I've been stuck on the same issue and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFVPFN3viag)
Now it works well in Blender well.

Comment: Recommend if you purchased this addon, seeking help from the vendor.